# Deleting selected autocomplete entries in Microsoft Edge

Tags: browser, autocomplete, microsoft-edge

Some form fields on web pages and the Location Bar and the Search Bar have autocomplete drop down lists that appear with a list of previously-entered data.

How can I delete **selected** entries in such drop down lists in **Microsoft Edge** browser?

---

*Note: Please do not respond with answers that advise to remove all entries.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete entry in Auto Complete in Microsoft Edge](http://superuser.com/questions/962527/how-to-delete-entry-in-auto-complete-in-microsoft-edge)

Answer (score 6):

For the new Chromium-based Microsoft Edge browser, this works:

1. Type in the address bar
2. Use the down arrow key to highlight the suggestion entry you want to delete
3. press shift + Delete

Source: [How to delete SPECIFIC autofill entries from Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1289097/how-to-delete-specific-autofill-entries-from-google-chrome)

Comment: this doesn't work for me

Comment: In which step do you get stuck? If it's step 3, there's a cross mark to the right of each entry now. Try clicking that.

Comment: Unfortunately, not here either. I'm running Microsoft Edge Version 111.0.1661.44 (Official build) (arm64), (installed just this week) and there's no X mark to the right of any entry, and Shift + Delete does not work either. Also tried Control + delete, option + delete, and command + delete. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a text editor.

1. Close all edge windows.
2. Find this file:

> typedurls.json

```
"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\RoamingState\typedurls.json"
```

3. Search for the entry. ie. `bing.com`
4. Remove *entire* json entry.

example:

```
{"VisitCount":1,"URL":"https://bing.com/","DateUpdatedLow":1588077197,"DateUpdatedHigh":30529921},
```

5. **Save** the file.
6. Start edge.
7. **Close** edge.
8. Start edge *again*.
9. Test the auto-complete bar.

This worked for me. I had to launch and close edge at least one time for it to flush the cache out of memory.

Comment: I just realized I might have answered the wrong question. Are you asking about the url bar? I should probably remove this answer.

Comment: The question says "Some form fields on web pages **and the Location Bar** and the Search Bar have autocomplete drop down lists", so I'd call this a partial answer, and I think it should stay. Perhaps it might be better if it were on a question specifically about the location bar instead, but it's fine. Also, I've written up [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1326305/776028) to cover the form data portion of this question.

Comment: I got here from 3D1T0R's link and it is exactly what I needed.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: The suggested `RoamingState` folder is empty for me.

Comment: This question was asked when it was the old Edge not based on Chromium. So I have no idea if it is still valid.

Comment: Incase it helps anyone else, if the site is in your favorites it will always pop up in your suggested URL bar.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for removing and/or editing form data entries. For how to remove an entry from the location bar's history of typed urls, see [Ben L's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1325949/776028).

Note: I don't know about older versions of Microsoft Edge, but this works on Windows 10 version `1803` build `17134.48` which includes Microsoft Edge version `42.17134.1.0` and Microsoft EdgeHTML version `17.17134`.
Also, I'm currently using a high resolution monitor with scaling turned on, so my screenshots might be appear a bit larger than what you'll see on your monitor.

1. Click the ". . ." button at the top right of the Microsoft Edge window.
   [image: "..." / "Settings and more" menu button]
2. Near the bottom of the menu that appears, click "Settings".
   [image]
3. Near the bottom of the sidebar that appears, there's a section labeled "Advanced Settings", in there, click "View advanced settings".
   [image: View advanced settings]
4. Now look for the "Autofill Settings" section, and click "Manage form entries".
   [image: Autofill settings > Manage form entries]
5. Hover your mouse over the entry you want to delete, and click the X that appears at the top right corner of it.

   Note: This screen also sports an "Add new" button so you can add another entry if desired. Clicking this opens a blank copy of the form in the following step for you to fill out for yourself.
   [image: A list of some example entries, with one highlighted because my cursor is hovering over it which causes the delete "X" to show.]
6. If you only want to remove (or alter) some of the information associated with one of these entries, you can click on the entry, edit it, and click "Save" at the bottom.
   [image: Autofill "Edit form entry" with some text changed]

Answer (score -1):

In older versions of Internet Explorer you could bring up the autocomplete list then hover over the entry with your mouse and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. This would clear the entry.

I will try to find some documentation regarding this in Edge. According to one [Microsoft engineer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/delete-autofill-in-edge/86cedc9b-a892-42e3-b85d-b8d9d7e50cbd) it is all or nothing.

> - Launch Microsoft Edge
> - Click the 3 dots (...) in top right corner and click Settings
> - Click View Advance Settings
> - Under Privacy and services, you can turn settings to off

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, which asks for selected entries, not all autocomplete entries.

Answer (score -2):

Click on the `...` in the top right corner, then click settings, find the clear browsing history, click the grey button the says choose what to clear. Check all the boxes that you want to clear. I suggest almost all of them except your passwords (that are used for auto sign in), unless you want those gone also.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, which asks for selected entries, not all autocomplete entries.