# How to delete entry in Auto Complete in Microsoft Edge

Tags: autocomplete, microsoft-edge

How do I delete an unwanted entry in AutoComplete in Microsoft Edge?  I have tried everything including highlighting with the down arrows and nothing works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting selected autocomplete entries in Microsoft Edge](https://superuser.com/questions/956091/deleting-selected-autocomplete-entries-in-microsoft-edge)

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to delete ALL entries in AutoComplete but not to delete only one.

Go to "settings" "advanced" and choose delete passwords.  It gets rid of everything and then you can re-enter the correct ones again.  If anyone can figure out how to delete only one, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To delete an individual entry it is almost the same process as in chrome.
Settings, View Advanced and then Manage my saved passwords.  From here you can delete individual entries.

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work.