# How to delete specific autofill entries from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Not too long ago, Google Chrome allowed users to delete specific autofill entries - either by going into their “Settings -> Autofill Settings -> Delete” the specific entries, or by going to the form you want to delete the autofill entry for, mousing over / pressing down on your keyboard and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Neither of these two methods appear to work any more.

Does anyone know how to delete specific autofill entries from Google Chrome?

Note: I don’t want to delete my passwords / manage passwords.
Going to “Settings -> Advanced -> Passwords & Forms -> Autofill” settings doesn’t solve my problem.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and clearing autofill settings is *not* what I want; I want to delete *specific* autofill entries.

Comment: Shift + Delete solved it for me. Thx for posting / asking

Comment: Related: [browser - Remove auto-complete field entries in Google Chrome - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/171198/remove-auto-complete-field-entries-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 212):

Hopefully I haven't oversimplified but I think there'll be enough to answer your question.

Step 1 - For example, click in the "Username" field/input box and press the down arrow (this will bring up a list of remembered "username" auto-fill entries)

Step 2 - Use the down arrow key to highlight the username (auto-fill entry) you want to delete

Step 3 - Press shift+delete, or shift+alt+backspace if you have a Chromebook

Done.

Comment: And I did read your post but I provided my answer because I JUST did it right before answering your question. I am using Chrome browser version 63.0.3239.140 on an updated Chromebook (not sure why shift+delete didn't work for you unless you have a Chromebook without a delete key and so it has to be shift+alt+backspace, fyi alt+backspace = delete).

Comment: It took some experimenting with the modifier keys, but I finally found that on a macbook, it's `[SHIFT]+[FN]+[BACKSPACE]`

Comment: This works, thanks. Why can't Chrome make it work like: right click on the option and delete?

Comment: Thanks so much. Not sure why this feature isn't documented clearly in Chrome.

Comment: Works in chrome 98 (2022) - it *used* to be hover the entry with mouse and press delete, now its hover the entry with mouse OR arrow-keys up/down to highlight the entry and shift+delete

Comment: On a macbook it is [SHIFT] + [FN] + [DELETE] (there is no backspace key on macbooks!)

Comment: And to chain multiple removals without moving the mouse each time (as delete clears focus), use down: Down > Shift+Delete > Down > Shift+Delete > ...

Comment: Random question but I can't find the answer anywhere... How do you UNDO this? I accidentally deleted an entry and now Chrome autocomplete will never remember that entry again, even though it IS in my saved passwords.

Answer (score 88):

**For macOS:**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Delete (backspace)</kbd>

Comment: Worked for me, but my MBP has a Delete key, not Backspace.

Comment: Doesn't work on saved passwords =/

Comment: This is the only thing that works on Mac. Shift+Delete does not work on Mac

Comment: Apple calls their "Backspace" key "Delete". Chrome still thinks of it as Backspace. On a Mac, Fn+Delete is "Forward Delete", which Chrome thinks of as the regular Delete key. So in a way, this is still Shift+Del, since Del = Fn+delete. I'm worried my explanation is confusing, but there you are.

Answer (score 16):

Based on Brian R. Quigley method:

After clicking inside any auto fill  field, you can hover by mouse on the desired entry then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. This works like a charm on Chrome in Windows.

Comment: This one works on Linux.

Comment: Finally! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

On a mac, adding the Fn. key is only needed when you have the short keyboard, in the long full sized keyboard you can use Shift+delete keys same as in windows the reason for this is the default del key in the short keyboard is actually a backspace key, but pressing Fn key will turn it to Del

If it’s bookmarked, it won’t be deleted when you press fn+shift+delete. You have to delete the bookmark first.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like google has moved the chrome settings around. I'm not sure if this has to do with your issue, but I just deleted a specific autofill entry by going to settings > passwords (under people just below sync). I also turned off "offer to save passwords" because that was the source of my pain. Random people who logged into amazon in my case, were cluttering my AWS login autofill...