# Delete all autocomplete entries in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, autocomplete, forms

**I want to remove all autocomplete entries in Google Chrome, and start from scratch.**

That is, I do not want to turn off autocomplete entirely, but rather:

- Remove all the existing stored autocomplete entries, and then
- Start accumulating autocomplete entries from then on.

(1) I am aware of these solutions, in which I can remove individual autocomplete entries one by one using <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> on a Mac:

- [Remove auto-complete field entries in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/q/171198/638668)
- [How to delete specific autofill entries from Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/q/1289097/638668)
- [How to remove one or all auto-complete text entries in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/q/175250/638668)
- [Clear autofill form data - Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/q/1436839/638668)

But this is very manual labor-intensive, because I have many entries in many fields on many web pages. For example, `Edit summary` field *alone* on Stack Overflow has dozens of entries. Other sites and fields have similar numbers of autofill entries, each of which has to be removed individually.

(2) This method (`Chrome menu` > `History` > `Clear browsing data`) did not work (history and current logins were removed, but the autofill entries were not removed):

- [Turn off text box suggestions - Google Chrome Community](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/179523826/turn-off-text-box-suggestions?hl=en)

(3) I also tried this method, which "almost" worked:

In the URL bar, enter `chrome://settings/addresses`

Select:

`Save and fill addresses`
`Includes information like phone numbers, email addresses, and shipping addresses`: <kbd>off</kbd>

This works in that it disables autocomplete. But it does not remove the autofill entries entirely: once it is turned back <kbd>on</kbd>, the old autocomplete entries are restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to remove all autocomplete entries in Google Chrome

As follows:

> 1. Open Chrome
> 2. Click the three dot symbol > More Tools > Clear browsing data...
> 3. Click the Advanced tab in the new window, and select All time from the drop down.
> 4. Check the Autofill form data box. Be sure to unselect all others if you do not wish to delete other data

Make sure you scroll down to see the above check box.

> 5. Click the Clear data button

Source: [TeamPassword | How to Clear Autofill on Chrome: Protect Your Internet Security by Clearing Chrome’s Saved Information](https://teampassword.com/blog/how-to-clear-autofill-on-chrome-protect-your-internet-security-by-clearing-chromes-saved-information)